# DoubleAnimation for textblock height

Tags: wpf

I have a textblock which should only show 2 lines of the text, while it is unselected. As soon as it gets selected, I want it to expand smoothly.

I started with something like:

```
<BeginStoryboard>
  <Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation
      Storyboard.TargetName="Second" 
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.MaxHeight)"
      To="50.0" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
  </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

But the issue here is, that I don't know how big the text is.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `From='0'` instead, which would start the animation with a value of `0` and end with whatever the value of `MaxHeight` is. However, that raises a different problem, as `MaxHeight` defaults to infinity, which would make the animation far too fast. Adding an `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyframes` at the start that sets `MaxHeight` to `ActualHeight` might work to resolve this. Something like this:

```
<BeginStoryboard>
  <Storyboard>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyframes
      Storyboard.TargetName='Second'
      Storyboard.TargetProperty='(TextBlock.MaxHeight)'>
      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{Binding TargetName=Second, Path=ActualHeight}" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyframes>
    <DoubleAnimation
      Storyboard.TargetName="Second" 
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.MaxHeight)"
      From="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
  </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. (Besides that I had to use `ElementName` instead of `TargetName`). But this first collapses all of the text, and then animates to the previously set `MaxHeight`. :/

Answer (score -3):

You can use **DoubleAnimation** to implement this. I have implemented this in a sample application.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnGotFocus">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="textBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.Value>
                    <System:Double>NaN</System:Double>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.Value>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnLostFocus">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="textBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.Value>
                    <System:Double>NaN</System:Double>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.Value>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="30" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.GotFocus" SourceName="textBox">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnGotFocus}" />
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.LostFocus" SourceName="textBox">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnLostFocus_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnLostFocus}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Your code for textbox should be :

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox"
         Height="30"
         HorizontalAlignment="Right"
         Text="Hello World" />
```

This will animate the textbox to a specified height as soon as it gets focussed. I have added an animation to collapse it as well when it loses focus.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Like I said, I don't want to expand it to a *specific* height. I can't give any information what height is enough. It depends on the text, which is user input.